# Identify international orders from domestic

Tags: db2

I am trying to distinguish domestic customers from international customers.
I can do it in SQL but I need to do it in DB2.
In SQL I would say.

```
Select
DCSCRY,
case when ocrh.dcscry = '   ' then 'BLANK' else case when ocrh.dcscry <> 'US ' then 'Y' else '' end 
end as INTER
from ocrh
```

Result

```
DCSCRY   INTER

 US
 US 
 CA        Y
 CA        Y
```

Any advice in DB2?

Comment: Same syntax in Db2 is valid for Db2-LUW. If you get some error, you should edit your question to show exactly the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the SQL you've shown is valid anywhere...nor does it match the results you've shown...

`when ocrh.dcscry = '   ' then 'BLANK'`

But your results don't show the string `BLANK`

```
DCSCRY   INTER
```

In any event you've got an extra `else` and `case` in the statement you've posted.  The correct syntax is

```
case
  when
  when
  else  
end
```

So your statement should be

```
Select
  DCSCRY,
  case 
    when ocrh.dcscry = '   ' then 'BLANK' 
    when ocrh.dcscry <> 'US ' then 'Y' 
    else '' 
  end as INTER
from ocrh
```